# Visual Studio and IIS Web Deploy URL + Multi-homed server

Tags: visual-studio, iis, windows-server-2012, multihomed

I have an IIS Server that is multi-homed, i.e. two IP addresses, bound to two different web sites. I just set up the second web site with a test page for now. Everything works as expected, i.e. can access outside the corporate firewall via dns records, can leverage off of Wild card SSL Certificate.

I'm already using web deploy with the first site, set up via "Configure Web Deploy Publishing", URL for publishing is, https://{local server name snipped}:8172/msdeploy.axd. Have no issue deploying from Visual Studio to that URL. Works perfect. Problem now is how do I deploy to second site? The  Configure dialog for second site comes up with the same URL for publishing, and my mind says I need to use a different URL or a different port that differentiates site 2 from site 1 but, a quick google search says I can't change the web deploy port to anything else.

How to overcome this?

Comment: 1) You don't need multiple IP addresses on IIS 8 and above, as SNI allows you to host multiple HTTPS sites side by side. 2) The single Web Deploy service allows you to deploy multiple sites. You just need to make sure you initialize the deployment on the right site. Take a look at `*.deploy.cmd` if you are running the command line, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/deploying-web-packages

Comment: As Lex Li said, a single Web Deploy service can handle the deployment of multiple sites on the same default port 8172. Because Web Deploy uses the site name to distinguish between different sites and deploy to the correct site, you only need to specify the correct site name in the publish configuration file.

Comment: @YurongDai that's the clarification I needed, "you only need to specify the correct site name". Thank you and to Lex Li's answer as well. Cheers mates.